# Why is it that so many Churches have a problem with Halloween but not with the other pagan holidays?

Tags: holidays

Can anyone give me a good reason to how it is ok to celebrate the resurrection of Yehoshu'a Immanuel in Pagan Ritual. And also to celebrate his birth in Pagan Ritual, even though he was not born in December to begin with. But it is such a bad thing to celebrate Halloween? And don't even try to go the stick with your traditions crap because when that was said these pagan holidays were not celebrated by Yehoshu'a and his disciples if anything we should be celebrating Yehoshu'a's birth during the feast of tabernacles and his resurrection on the feast of the Passover since these were the traditions of that time and they were what was practiced by the people the are in the Bible. And are the ones that closely relate to each event. But I imagine some of you will say that you are not Jewish so that is why you do not celebrate the feast days even though so much Bible prophecy is tied to them.

Comment: I guess your question itself has the answer. We celebrate **Yehoshu'a** (if you want to call him that) birth on Christmas. But what does Halloween has to do with **Yehoshu'a** ??? That is why many churches have a problem with that. BTW what is the difference between `Yehoshu'a Immanuel` and `Yehoshu'a birth`? (Just asking as you have mentioned them as two different things)

Comment: Not to be sarcastic, but... For the same reason some have issues with witches and wizards in Harry Potter, but not with the ones in the Wizard of Oz?  I know that ***sounds*** sarcastic, but it's not meant that way.  It's a lead-up to this:  There are so many people with so many opinions on this and that, that it'd be impossible to answer in a way that would be true for all who have a problem with Halloween.  It's the definition of "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: The generic answer is that Christians object to the [pagan festival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samhain). Although the dates of Christmas and Easter may have their roots in paganism, to celebrate Christmas and Easter is not to celebrate a pagan feast: if anything, those feasts have been suppressed almost to extinction.

Comment: Every day belongs to God.  The fact that pagans have a celebration on one of His days does not preclude us Christians from celebrating God on the same day.

Comment: To the downvoters and close-voters: This question really isn't opinion-based. Sure, there are many opinions about Halloween, but that's not what the question is asking. The question is asking why many people oppose Halloween--and there is a specific, non-opinion answer to that. It's also not 'too broad', IMO, because he's asking for an overview of "many churches." He's not asking "Do Christians oppose Halloween?"--which would be opinion-based and broad. He's asking why it is opposed by those who do. I believe it sufficiently specifies the scope of the question, according to our guidlines.

Comment: @Joshua So, here's my issue with your question - it doesn't really seek to gain knowledge, but rather discussion.  We are very academic here - we ask questions that have answers.  This reads much more like a polemic - Halloween is bad (and I may or may not agree with that) - How could anyone be so stupid as to...  If you were to change the tone, I'd retract my VTC. As it stands, however, no...

Comment: Why do churches have "Halloween" alternative parties which include dressing up and giving out candy?  My wife has a HUGE problem with Halloween.  I just remind her that our son is not sacrificing cats to the sun god, he just dressing up (as a superhero) and showing it off to the neighbors.  I slept on the couch for that.  This seems to be a better conversation in CHAT than a question as there will not be one definitive answer.

Comment: @SomeFreeMason: But there *is* one definitive answer to why many Christians oppose Halloween.

Comment: @Flimzy I guess so, if you're willing to accept an ambiguous answer such as, "they think it's evil".  When you dig into the history of it, it's a modern invention.  As is the Yule tree and Christmas.

Comment: This question is a lot like my question "Why do Christians think Freemasons are evil?"  It's hard to say since someone heard something sometime and it snowballed from there.  Halloween is similar.  We were told to be afraid of it... we're not exactly sure why as there are no references to it in the bible.  It is strictly denominational.  There are plenty of other Holidays that someone could say are Pegan and we would throw stones at people who celebrate them.  Even though they're okay today.  What if someone said President's day is worshiping man and not God?

Comment: Voting to close because of your sarcastic attitude. Also, because the question is not really a question. When was the last time you saw anybody going to church for a Halloween celebration?

Comment: @fredsbend Not to defend the OP, but there were several "Halloween Alternative" events at local churches in my area 8 days ago.  I do agree that this question is troll bait.

Comment: @SomeFreeMason: I see this primarily as a question of "Why is Halloween different from other 'pagan' holidays that Christians celebrate?" The answer that is not nearly as ambiguous.

Comment: The dualistic features of the following holidays are: Christmas: Jesus birth/Santa Claus. Easter: The Cross/The Easter egg.  Halloween (Hell or win): The last judgement/trick or treat?

Comment: @fгedsbend asks "*When was the last time you saw anybody going to church for a Halloween celebration?*".  Consider the [Day of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dead), which is celebrated by millions of Catholics every year.

Comment: @RayButterworth Christian syncretism has always been more like Christian rites subsuming pagan days and rites, rather than actual mixing. Christmas is not pagan, but some solstice feasts certainly are. Halloween is pagan, and Day of the Dead is an interesting Christian alternative that may one day subsume it. But they are not the same things. As for celebrating Halloween secularly, some Christians see a problem and some don't.

Comment: @fгedsbend. I find it difficult to reconcile accepting pagan practices with scripture such as "*Thus saith the LORD, Learn not the way of the heathen …*" Jeremiah 10:2, "*But in vain they do worship me, teaching for doctrines the commandments of men.*"  Matthew 15:9, and "*Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we not … in thy name done many wonderful works? And then will I profess unto them, I never knew you: depart from me, ye that work iniquity.*" Matthew 7:22–23.

Comment: @RayButterworth The actual paganism the scripture references is washed away. When was the last time you were offered meat sacrificed to an idol? Or sat in on a pagan prayer/worship? Carving pumpkins is hardly pagan.

Comment: @fгedsbend, "*Rogers, Nicholas (2003). Halloween: From Pagan Ritual to Party Night. Oxford University Press. ISBN 978-0-19-514691-2*" would disagree.

Answer (score 8):

When Christians and/or churches oppose Halloween, it is because the holiday is perceived as a celebration and glorification of evil.  Children (and adults) dress up as ghosts, witches, monsters, and all manner of "evil" thing.  Many claim (although my research suggests that historical evidence is lacking to support such claims) that the tradition of dressing as other creatures--even non-evil ones (angels, plumbers, etc) has a pagan spiritual significance that is anti-Christian.

You don't see this on Christmas or Easter.  While it's true these holidays are celebrated on what were once pagan holidays, for reasons of history which are beyond the scope of this answer, they do not glorify evil.

Now, having said that, there are Christians who refuse to celebrate Christmas and Easter for the very reason that they are originally pagan holidays. And many Christian groups celebrate the birth of Christ on different days than December 25, as well.

There are also many Christians who celebrate Halloween in one form or another; often choosing not to dress as an "evil" creature, or perhaps having a party that doesn't even involve costumes, etc.

Comment: How is Easter "originally a pagan holiday"? The date is based on the Jewish calendar relative to Passover and is firmly grounded in scripture.

Answer (score 3):

What Churches, and Christians alike do not like about Halloween is not the celebration, but the fact that they believe Evil, Satan, Demons and etcetera, are real.

Because they believe that they fear that such celebrations minimize the danger posed by those beings.

They also worry that children will learn to not fear evil, and thereby become more susceptible to being influenced by them.

Many Christians feel that the depredated state of our society is directly related to the mitigation of the danger which those entities pose.

At any rate the current course of our society, is contrary to the ideals of we Christians today, and we are very apprehensive about exactly what effect it is having on our religion.

For example; the recent denial of Military Chaplains to pray in the name of Jesus. That we pray in the name of Jesus is one of the fundamental precepts of Christianity, and to deny a Christian Chaplain to do so is to cause him to be at odds with his faith.

There are innumerable other situations I could site, but I feel that my point has been adequately stated.